# Google Analytics - Ignore dropoffs on page

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

When a user only visits one page on the site, and doesn't visit again for a while, it's considered a "drop off". The site I have is a online game and many users only visit the "play" page when visiting the site, which is marked as a "drop off". This isn't true as they're actually playing the game for 30+ minutes and that is not a drop off.

Other than forcing people to go to the game page through another page (creating 2 requests), how can I have dropoffs ignored on a page without messing up other stats like pageviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent article on the Google Analytics blog dealt with tracking adjusted bounce rate for visitors who stay on a single page for an extended amount of time: [Tracking Adjusted Bounce Rate In Google Analytics](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/07/tracking-adjusted-bounce-rate-in-google.html). It sounds like in your case the bounce and drop-off rate are related.

The solution is to make a tracking event call after some amount of time has passed, something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'timer', 'in play')}, 60000);
```

In your case, I'd be tempted to continue to make event tracking calls periodically, including the opt-value parameter to track session time -- this would allow you to track on GA play time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean drop offs as shown on the "Visitors Flow" report, which I believe correlates to exits.  If you're having a problem with visitors "exiting" your site due to being on the same page for a long period of time, then it sounds like you need to extend your session timeout length.

Google Analytics defaults to a 30 minute session length, instructions for changing it can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSessionCookieTimeout).

Comment: The problem is that they only visit that one page on the site the entire time they're there. If a person only visits that one page the entire time they're playing, does Google not think that's a bounce/exit?